# Erlang Apple Push notification not getting response-error before disconnect

Tags: ssl, erlang, apple-push-notifications, gen-server

I'm currently testing a bit my push notification module.
When the Device Token is invalid, it disconnects...

According to [Apple push notification developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) I should get an error-response packet just before the apple push server disconnect...

The thing is I get disconnected, but I do not get anything on the Socket just before that, and I need to know if the push failed because of a malformed push (so I can fix the bug), or an invalid device token (so I can remove it from the database).

Here's my code :

```
-module(pushiphone).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start/1, init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, code_change/3, handle_info/2, terminate/2]).

-import(ssl, [connect/4]).
-record(push, {socket, state, cert, key}).

start(Provisioning) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [Provisioning], []).

init([Provisioning]) ->
    gen_server:cast(self(), {connect, Provisioning}),
    {ok, #push{}}.

send(Socket, DT, Payload) ->
    PayloadLen = length(Payload),
    DTLen = size(DT),
    PayloadBin = list_to_binary(Payload),
    Packet = <<0:8, 
           DTLen:16/big, 
           DT/binary, 
           PayloadLen:16/big, 
           PayloadBin/binary>>,
    ssl:send(Socket, Packet).

handle_call(_, _, P) ->
    {noreply, P}.

handle_cast({connect, Provisioning}, P) ->
    case Provisioning of
    dev -> Address = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
    prod -> Address = "gateway.push.apple.com"
    end,
    Port = 2195,
    Cert="/apns-" ++ atom_to_list(Provisioning) ++ "-cert.pem",
    Key="/apns-" ++ atom_to_list(Provisioning) ++ "-key.pem",
    Options = [{certfile, Cert}, {keyfile, Key}, {password, "********"}, {mode, binary}, {active, true}],
    Timeout = 1000,
    {ok, Socket} = ssl:connect(Address, Port, Options, Timeout),
    {noreply, P#push{socket=Socket}};
handle_cast(_, P) ->
    {noreply, P}.

handle_info({ssl, Socket, Data}, P) ->
    <<Command, Status, SomeID:32/big>> = Data,
    io:fwrite("[PUSH][ERROR]: ~p / ~p / ~p~n", [Command, Status, SomeID]),
    ssl:close(Socket),
    {noreply, P};
handle_info({push, message, DT, Badge, [Message]}, P) ->
    Payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" ++ Message ++ "\",\"badge\":" ++ Badge ++ ",\"sound\":\"" ++ "msg.caf" ++ "\"}}",
    send(P#push.socket, DT, Payload),
    {noreply, P};
handle_info({ssl_closed, _SslSocket}, P) ->
    io:fwrite("SSL CLOSED !!!!!!~n"),
    {stop, normal, P};
handle_info(AnythingElse, P) ->
    io:fwrite("[ERROR][PUSH][ANYTHING ELSE] : ~p~n", [AnythingElse]),
    {noreply, P}.

code_change(_, P, _) ->
    {ok, P}.

terminate(_, _) ->
    ok.
```

It works great when the payload and the deviceToken are both right. if deviceToken is invalid, it only get's disconnected.

Does anyone can spot the issue ? because after 4 hours of searching, I have only found out that I clearly can't !

Here's the error-response table :

```
Status code     Description
0           No errors encountered
1           Processing error
2           Missing device token
3           Missing topic
4           Missing payload
5           Invalid token size
6           Invalid topic size
7           Invalid payload size
8           Invalid token
255         None (unknown)
```

Comment: Do you see this behaviour for sandbox and/or production gateways?

Comment: How to do if the ssl connection is lose ?

Comment: @why you simply reconnect when closed... I suggest having a pool of connections to pushs server if one is down, there is always other while you reconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the *simple notification format* as defined by figure 5-1 in the apple documentation you've linked to (judging by your `send()` function). When this format is used, no error response is provided when the request is malformed - you just get the disconnect.

To get the error response you should be using the *enhanced notification format* detailed in figure 5-2.